# How to change .animate to .css so it doesn't conflict with a CSS3 animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Below is part of the code I'm using to navigate through a CSS3 slideshow thats being animated with a cubic bezier and timed with keyframes.

At the moment this line of code...

```
$("#carousel .video-list").animate({'left' : left_indent}, 1000, function () {
```

… is conflicting with the current css i have as I've learnt they cannot be used together. My question is how do I edit that line of code so that it's .css instead of .animate in order for it to function and not conflict with my css3 animation?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/2/)

JS

```
var item_width = $("#carousel .video-list li").outerWidth();
var left_value = item_width * (-1);

//if user clicked on prev button
$('#previous').click(function () {
    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($("#carousel .video-list").css('left')) + item_width;
    //slide the item            
$("#carousel .video-list").animate({'left' : left_indent}, 1000, function () {

    $(".video-list, #timeline, .description-list").css({"animation-play-state": "paused", 
"-webkit-animation-play-state": "paused"});

    //move the last item and put it as first item                
    $("#carousel .video-list li:first").before($("#carousel .video-list li:last"));
    //set the default item to correct position
    $("#carousel .video-list").css({'left' : left_value});

    $("#myVideo").get(0).play();
    $("#myVideoTwo").get(0).play();
    $("#myVideoThree").get(0).play();
    $("#myVideoFour").get(0).play();

});
//cancel the link behavior            
return false;

});
```

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: I've just made this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/akZ48/2/ to demonstrate the setup and whats happening. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a cross-browser solution by any means, but you could still do this with CSS and listen for the `transitionend` event. The Javascript would look something like this:

```
$("#carousel .video-list").bind( 'transitionend', function() {

    $(".video-list, #timeline, .description-list").css({"animation-play-state": "paused", "-webkit-animation-play-state": "paused"});

    // More code that's currently in the animation complete handler

});
$("#carousel .video-list").css({ left       : left_indent
                                 transition : 'all 1000ms linear'});
```

I make no warranties if that fixes your problem, but it sounds like you are looking for a way to have the `.animate()` completion event handler fire the code that's currently in there event though you're using CSS transitions.

By the way, jQuery will make the `transition` property you're passing into the `.css()` method cross-browser automatically (i.e. include vendor prefixes where necessary)

Also, it's worth noting that there is another event you can listen for to handle animations that are ending. Instead of `transitionend`, you would bind to `animationend`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this function being inside of the click function:

```
$("#carousel .video-list").animate({'left' : left_indent}, 1000, function () {
```

Pull the function outside of it and use this:

```
function animateList(left_indent) {
```

Then inside of your click function change it to be:

```
var item_width = $("#carousel .video-list li").outerWidth();
var left_value = item_width * (-1);

$('#previous').click(function () {
    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($("#carousel .video-list").css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item   
    animateList(left_indent);

    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;
});
```

Updated animateList() function

```
function animateList(left_indent) {
    $(".video-list, #timeline, .description-list").css({"animation-play-state":"paused", "-webkit-animation-play-state": "paused"});

    //move the last item and put it as first item                
    $("#carousel .video-list li:first").before($("#carousel .video-list li:last"));

    //set the default item to correct position
    $("#carousel .video-list").css({'left' : left_value});

    $("#myVideo").get(0).play();
    $("#myVideoTwo").get(0).play();
    $("#myVideoThree").get(0).play();
    $("#myVideoFour").get(0).play();
}
```

This removes the javasctipt animation so you can use a CSS transition instead, based on the left property.

```
#carousel .video-list {
    -webkit-transition: left ease 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: left ease 2s;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'm a little confused about the order I should put things? Also how would it know to slide to the left without there being a transition or animation?

Comment: I've tried implementing this but it just does the same thing? Am I supposed to add something to this? Many thanks

Comment: You need to add the CSS transtion. I removed the javascript animation so that you could translate on the left value. I can update with an example

Comment: If you wouldn't mind I think it would help me understand it better. Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: I took all the code out before so just putting it back in to try will let you know if it works as soon as i'm done.

Comment: Does it matter what way round I have the animateList function in relation to #previous .click function? It doesn't seem to be working at the minute. It's doing everything but the slide transition.

Comment: I didn't have the first two lines in my example because they were unchanged. Make sure you didn't remove `var item_width = $("#carousel .video-list li").outerWidth();` and `var left_value = item_width * (-1);`

Comment: Yep I kept them in at the top, it doesn't seem to be working. A css transition wouldn't be conflicting with a css animation applied to that same element (#carousel .video-list) would it?

Comment: All the JS does is change the left value on `#carousel .video-list`. The javascript should work without animation or transitions. If it doesn't work, there is something else going on here and you would need to debug the javascript.

Comment: The javascript works fine. It's changing from slide to slide when you click previous or next its just not transitioning i.e its not sliding from slide to slide with the transition ease its just jumping?

Comment: This code is getting executed immediately because it's in the click handler. The code I recommended above waits until the transition event ends so you're chaining everything. If you add an `.delay(1000)` or `setTimeout()` you can delay this from happening too. Going with this approach assumes you have the timing set in the CSS and the Javascript and is a little brittle because you now have the same value you have to maintain in two different places. Additionally, if, for some reason, the timing gets off (on a slower browser, or a mobile device that's running slow) the timing will be off too.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use `return false` to cancel the link behavior. There is a method called 'preventDefault()` that is better suited to this purpose. It's in the jQuery API docs if you're interested.